# SendMessage (F4) fails when sending it to window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sendmessage

Working with Visual Studio 6 (VC++ 6.0) I'm using an ActiveX datepicker control which I fail to show expanded by default ([3006216](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006216/dtpicker-how-to-open-up-an-control-expanded-by-default)). Alternatively I'm trying to send a keyboard message (F4) to my window to open up the control, but nothing happens when I do so...

```
// try 1: use the standard window handle
LRESULT result = ::SendMessage(m_hWnd,VK_F4, 0, 0);
// try 2: use just use the SendMessage
result = SendMessage(VK_F4);
```

result is always 0 - what can I do to test/verify the message sending?

Thanks in acvance a lot...

Olli

Comment: Check out: ["You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay - there's two approaches on this issue (thanks for all the help, guys!):

First: Use "::SendMessage" with correct message AND correct handle:

```
::SendMessage(m_wndDatePicker.m_hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F4, 0);
```

Alternatively use "SendInput":

```
// important: set focus to control first    
m_wndDatePicker.SetFocus(); 

INPUT *key;

key = new INPUT;
key->type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
key->ki.wVk = VK_F4;
key->ki.dwFlags = 0;
key->ki.time = 0;
key->ki.wScan = 0;
key->ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

SendInput(1,key,sizeof(INPUT));
```

Answer (score 0):

`VK_F4` is a key code, not a window message. Try this:

```
::SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F4, 0);
::SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_F4, 0);
```

Comment: Hm, thanks for your help. Unfortunately nothing has changed in the window's behaviour, sorry!

Comment: @Olli, check my edit. I didn't test the code, maybe a `WM_KEYDOWN` is also required.

Comment: @ Nick D: no improvement - any more ideas...?